# Geometry Proximity to recognise volume of in intersecting mesh collection

Tags: geometry-nodes

What I’m trying to achieve is a way to mix various functions by having them be covered by a mesh collection however so far my node set up can only recognise the edges so I’m looking to see if there is a way to force Geometry Proximity to recognise volume
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you trying to make an sdf?

Comment: no im actually trying to make a sort of brush. For context im making a terrain generator and I had an idea of making feature a where you place boundary boxes around certain parts then it applies a displacements and materials and that’s working so far but as you can see in this instance I have a ring from the perimeter of sphere mesh then I need a filled in dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this setup to check if object inside volume (by checking normal direction) and combine it with face proximity

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how to check for selections (if one mesh is inside another):

[image]
[image]

---

And this is how to get an SDF:

[image]
[image]
alternative SDF setup:
[image]

---

If you want the distance from the object but not a negative distance inside (like an SDF hase), you could set the inside to be 0.
Like this:
[image]
*this will visually look the same as an sdf in the viewport, because blender (or computers) don't display negative values anyway.*

---

Here is a useful nodegroup you could make:

[image]

[image]