Hide instances that intersect with an object
Dear Blender community
I am new to geometry nodes, and can't figure one thing on my own. I have those roof tiles as instances on points, nothing too fancy, but I want to hide some of the tiles in case if they intersect with a chosen object. How do I do that? Gut feeling tells me to dig into proximity nodes perhaps, but not sure.
Please see the pictures attached. All tiles that intersect with the sphere must disappear. No tiles must be cut in half (if I would want that, I would have just used boolean).
Thanks in advance!



To clarify your question: (1) is the masking object always a sphere (with a centre and a radius to compute distances...) or could it be a more complex object ? (2) do you want "not to instance" tiles (using the Selection mask of the Instance on Points node), or do you want to remove "realized" tiles afterwards ?

Hi Stef!
Instances must be realized. The shape could be anything, a sphere here is only for simplicity of explanation. In the matter of fact, I don't want the tiles inside the object removed, I want them to have another material. I just thought if I figure out how to remove, the rest I will also manage.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/300089/165102
